# .NET Core CLI - Listing and Filtering tests

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nunit, mstest

I would like to display a list of test filtered by category but when I execute the following command:

```
dotnet --filter="TestCategory!=ExcludeTest" --list-test
```

it seems that the `--list-test` of the .NET Core CLI does not take into account the `--filter`.
 Indeed, the brief [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21) suggests that all discovered tests are being displayed:

> -t | --list-tests
>
> List all of the discovered tests in the current project.

Is there a workaround ?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It works fine on my machine. What framework are you using? You added nunit as a tag. TestCategory is supported only with MSTest.

Comment: I'm using nunit as a test framework but it actually does support TestCategory. Which framework are you using ? Just MSTest ?

Comment: Yeah, just MSTest.